# Determining values when looping through multiple ranges in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro to set chart max and mins based on a dynamic data set. When the user chooses their group, the chart updates, and the macro runs to update the chart max and min values to an appropriate scale.

I am hoping someone can help me as I try to use variables from 3 ranges to:

1. Choose chart based on cell value in range
2. Set min based on cell value in range
3. Set max based on cell value in range

At this point I am able to pull out the chart name, but am having trouble getting the value for min and max from the range.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub rescale()

ActiveSheet.Calculate

Dim ChrtNmRng As Range
Dim ChrtMinRng As Range
Dim ChrtMaxRng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set ChrtNmRng = Sheets("Data").Range("o5:o20")
Set ChrtMinRng = Sheets("Data").Range("z5:z20")
Set ChrtMaxRng = Sheets("Data").Range("Aa5:Aa20")

For Each cell In ChrtNmRng

With Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects(cell.Value).Chart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = ChrtMinRng.Value
    .MaximumScale = ChrtMaxRng.Value
End With

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Use:  `.MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ChrtMinRng)`  `.MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ChrtMaxRng)`

Comment: Does this code find the min and max in that range? I have already found the min in max in the "Z" and "AA" columns, so I am just looking to pull the value from the same row for all 3 variables (NmRng, MinRng, MaxRng). Thanks!

Comment: Yes that code gets the min and max in that range. I am not quite clear what you need beyond that?

Comment: For instance for the first graph. The name is found in o5, the value for the graph axis minimum is found in A5 and the maximum is found in AA5. I need to assign those values to the MinimumScale and MaximumScale for that specified chart.

Once it has set those values, it needs to move to the next value in the range to set the max and min for the next chart.

Comment: See below - I get what you need (I think!)

Comment: Both answers below will do what you want but @AlexP is more succinct and deserves the correct mark.  Click the green check mark by the answer that you deem as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
Sub rescale()
    Dim ChrtNmRng As Range, cell As Range

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Set ChrtNmRng = Sheets("Data").Range("o5:o20")

    For Each cell In ChrtNmRng
        With Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects(cell.Value).Chart.Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = Range("Z" & cell.Row)
            .MaximumScale = Range("AA" & cell.Row)
        End With
     Next cell  
End Sub
```

The key here is that your ranges for the minimum and maximum values (`Z` and `AA`) line up precisely with column `O` so you can use the `row` reference to get the corresponding values you need.

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work. I think it might be that the min and max scale are on the "Data" sheet, but embedded in the With statement which points to the "Dashboard" sheet.

Comment: I will try this:
           ` .MinimumScale = Sheets("Data").Range("Z" & cell.Row)
            .MaximumScale = Sheets("Data").Range("AA" & cell.Row)`

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Just doing the final testing.

Comment: This worked great! Turned out I needed to change xlValue to xlCategory as I was looking to update the horizontal scale. Thanks for all your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your comments. Column O contains the name of the charts and the others contain what is wanted as the min and max for each of those charts.

```
Sub rescale()

ActiveSheet.Calculate

Dim ChrtNmRng As Range
Dim ChrtMinRng As Range
Dim ChrtMaxRng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ChrtNmRng = Sheets("Data").Range("o5:o20")
Set ChrtMinRng = Sheets("Data").Range("z5:z20")
Set ChrtMaxRng = Sheets("Data").Range("Aa5:Aa20")

For i = 1 To 16

With Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects(ChrtNmRng(i).Value).Chart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = ChrtMinRng(i).Value
    .MaximumScale = ChrtMaxRng(i).Value
End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Agreed - same concept as I thought of for my answer.

Comment: @Scott Craner This seems like a good option. The one concern is that the max, min, and chart name references are all on the "DATA" sheet, while the charts themselves are on the "DASHBOARD" sheet. I am working to update the code you provided to point to the correct sheet. Thanks :)

Comment: @bl3nd3r It should not matter, this does not replace your full code. only the for loop part.